# Jenkins warnings plugin gives different results from eclipse

Tags: jenkins, hudson, warnings, compiler-warnings, jenkins-plugins

I am using the Jenkins warnings plugin to display compiler warnings. Problem is: **The warnings I get from the Jenkins warnings plugin are different from the warnings I get in Eclipse.**

> e.g.
>
> - In Eclipse: I need an @SuppressWarnings("null")
> - In Jenkins: this annotation is marked as unnecessary

It looks like the warnings Plugin is using a different compiler compliance level than my Eclipse installation does. 
In Eclipse I am using Compiler compliance level 1.6.
**How can I find out and adjust the compliance level for Jenkins?**

Or is there another explanation for the differing warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the config of this job.Find the JDK checkbox, Is it default or sth else? Try to set it 1.6 and see.

Eclipse warnings can actually be [customized](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/compiler/ref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm). So I think the 
problem is that the eclipse compile warning settings are different with the Jenkins Compile settings.

You can try compile your code with `javac` and see if you get the same warnings with that in eclipse,if not,it should be a eclipse config issue.

Comment: Thanks Johnny. Where can I find this `JDK checkbox`? (didn't see one in the jobs config) In our build we are setting `-Djava_home` to a JDK 1.6 if that's of any help.

Comment: @kdzia see the jenkins global config,add jdk 1.6, maybe you haven't set it yet.Could be the reason

Comment: In the global jenkins config under `JDK` we have a JDK 1.6 set

Comment: Thanks :-) The difference seems to be due to customization in Eclipse. If I change the according setting in the Preferences `Preferences > Java > Compiler> Errors/Warnings > Null analysis > Potential null pointer access` to Ignore (which is the default) the behaviour is the same as in Jenkins. I don't assume there's a possibility to change this behaviour in Jenkins??

Comment: @kdzia Jenkins uses the standard JDK and should output all the warnings ,I don't think warnings  can be customized.